# SQL Query to find linked accounts under one ID

Tags: sql

I have a table name Customer where a customer has a unique identifier ID. Each ID can have more than once account of customer linked to it. I have to find how many accounts are linked under one ID and all the accounts linked under it.
Input:

```
| customer| account_no | ID  | 
|     RAM |        123 | ABC |
|     RAM |        456 | ABC | 
|     RAM |        789 | ABC | 
|     ADAM|        101 | DEF | 
|    ADAM |        102 | DEF | 
|    ALEX |        232 | GHI | 
|    ALEX |        534 | GHI |
```

Output:
I want to find IDs which have more than one account linked under it and the account numbers linked to it.
E.g.

```
|    ID   |Count_of_accounts| Accounts | 
|    ABC  |        3        | 123      | 
|         |                 | 456      |
|         |                 | 789      |
|    DEF  |        2        | 101      | 
|         |                 | 102      |
```

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags ,please only tag database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
   select ID , count(*) over (partition by ID) cnt, account_no
   from Customer
) t where cnt > 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT()` window functions:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.ID END ID,
       CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.Count_of_accounts END Count_of_accounts,
       t.Accounts
FROM (
  SELECT ID, account_no Accounts, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY account_no) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) Count_of_accounts
  FROM Customer
) t
WHERE t.Count_of_accounts > 1
ORDER BY t.ID, t.rn
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0e6e90fa5ad6512d7786ce3f16789602).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and `case`:

```
with to_r as (
   select c.*, row_number() over (order by id) r from customer c
),
rnk as (
   select r.*, exists (select 1 from to_r r1 where r1.r < r.r and r1.id = r.id) s from to_r r
)
select case when not s then r.id end ID,
       case when not s then (select sum(r1.id = r.id) from rnk r1) end Count_of_accounts,
       r.account_no Accounts
from rnk r;
```